# What is a good source for a version of MAME for macOS?

Tags: macos, emulation, mame

Is there any version of MAME for MACOS that is still up to date and still maintained?

- http://www.macmame.org/ last update: 2006
- http://mameosx.sourceforge.net/ last update: 2009

GUI would be nice, but it's not a must have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [SDL MAME for OS X](http://sdlmame.parodius.com/)? I don't have a Mac, so I can't try it to make sure it's works. It appears to be command-line, so no GUI, but it appears to be on version 142, which would match the PC version.

Comment: i have tied after i red your answer. It works fine thank you! (after installing the SDL runtime library) Now if you have any any GUI i can use you get a bonus point :P

Comment: @meo, glad it works! I will keep an eye out for a GUI ... MAME is playable without one but I agree with you, it is nice to have one, hopefully someone will work on one for Macs.